# How do I update the progress bar on my Pyside2 GUI?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, qml, pyside2

I've been trying to update my progress bar on my GUI but I can't figure out how to do it... The code I have provided shows the progress updating - I just need that value to update the progress bar on my GUI too! It's a QML file from Qt Creator.

main.py

```
import os
import sys
import time

from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine, qmlRegisterType
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Slot, Signal, QTimer, QUrl, QThread
from pathlib import Path

from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

class MainWindow(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    @Slot()
    def thread_progress(self):
        print("Worker")
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.start()
        self.worker.run()
        

class Worker(QObject):
    progress_value = Signal(float)

    @Slot()
    def run(self):
        self.progress = 0
        self.total = 100
        for i in range(0, self.total):
            self.update_progress()

    def update_progress(self):
        print(f"{self.progress} / {self.total}")
        self.progress += 1
        self.progress_value.emit(self.progress)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    # Get Context
    main = MainWindow()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend", main)
    # Set App Extra Info
    app.setOrganizationName("zardoss")
    app.setOrganizationDomain("N/A")

    engine.load(os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "main.qml"))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The main.py file connects with the main.qml file. The GUI has a button, progress bar and a text input element. I am only concerned with the progress bar filling up after the generate button has been pressed.
You can see from the console after pressing the generate button that the values from 1-100 are being filled up but it doesn't fill the progress bar as I am unsure how.

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.15
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.15

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    width: 750
    height: 500
    visible: true
    color: "#00000000"

    // Remove title bar
    flags: Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    // Properties
    property int windowStatus: 0
    property int windowMargin: 10

    title: qsTr("Progress Bar")
    Rectangle {
        id: bg
        color: "#2c313c"
        border.color: "#f12c313c"
        border.width: 1
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.rightMargin: windowMargin
        anchors.leftMargin: windowMargin
        anchors.bottomMargin: windowMargin
        anchors.topMargin: windowMargin
        z:1

        Rectangle {
            id: appContainer
            height: 480
            color: "#00000000"
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.rightMargin: 1
            anchors.leftMargin: 1
            anchors.bottomMargin: 1
            anchors.topMargin: 1

            Rectangle {
                id: content
                color: "#00000000"
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.top: topBar.bottom
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.topMargin: 0

                Button {
                    id: btnGenerate
                    x: 265
                    y: 44
                    width: 200
                    height: 50
                    text: "Generate"
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 0
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    anchors.verticalCenterOffset: 165
//                    colorPressed: "#1e5425"
//                    colorMouseOver: "#42b852"
                    font.pointSize: 14
                    display: AbstractButton.TextBesideIcon
                    font.bold: false
//                    colorDefault: "#328a3f"
                    anchors.rightMargin: 250
                    onPressed: {
                        // backend.generate()
                        backend.thread_progress()
                    }
                }

                ProgressBar{
                    id: progressBar
                    x: 239
                    y: 64
                    visible: true
                    width: 661
                    height: 250
//                    text: "%"
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    value: 0
                    //bgColor: "#00000/*000"
                    //dropShadowColor: "#20000000"
                    //samples: 16
                    anchors.verticalCenterOffset: -15
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    DropShadow{
        anchors.fill: bg
        horizontalOffset: 0
        verticalOffset: 0
        radius: 10
        samples: 16
        color: "#80000000"
        source:bg
        z: 0
    }

    Connections{
        target: backend

        function onLinkValid(valid)  {
            if(valid === true)    {
                textField.textColor = "#00FF00"
            } else {
                textField.textColor = "#FF00FF"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mre], not external links

Comment: There are a lot of file to go with it - contained in the repo. It's easier for everyone to just clone the repo and run it rather than manually copy+pasting and downloading the necessary files.

Comment: The objective of SO is not to help a user to implement their project but to solve a specific problem so that other users can have it as a reference for future problems. Therefore, the post must be self-contained, that is, they must not depend on an external resource since, for example, the links could be broken in the future making the post unusable.

Comment: If your project is small then it would be a good candidate for MRE, but if it is not then you will have to work to make it so: Either delete files that are irrelevant to the current problem and copy all the code in your post, or create a new one. project focused only on functionality and copy the code in your post. Also read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: @zardoss sorry but that's *your* point of view. And on what base, security wise, could we just clone and run some random repo we know nothing about? In any case, we certainly cannot go through that "lot of file" for you to find the specific point related to your issue, that's your part of the job. Please, carefully read the given links, and follow their suggestions.

Comment: @eyllanesc Apologies guys, that makes sense. I will edit the post.

Comment: Is this sufficient to open the question back up? @eyllanesc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your case is that the signal that has the progress value is not connected to any element of the GUI.

In this case, a signal must be created in the class exposed to QML that connects with the ProgressBar, and this signal must receive information from the signal from the Worker. On the other hand, you should not invoke the "run()" method directly since it will be executed in the thread from which it was invoked, which in your case is the main thread so it will block the GUI, instead you must invoke it indirectly with a signal or using the QTimer.

```py
import os
import sys
import time
from pathlib import Path

from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Slot, Signal, QTimer, QUrl, QThread


class Backend(QObject):
    progress_changed = Signal(float, name="progressChanged")

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.progress_changed.connect(self.progress_changed)
        self.worker_thread = QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)
        self.worker_thread.start()

    @Slot()
    def start_worker(self):
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.worker.run)


class Worker(QObject):
    progress_changed = Signal(float)

    @Slot()
    def run(self):
        self.progress = 0
        self.total = 100
        for i in range(0, self.total):
            self.update_progress()

    def update_progress(self):
        print(f"{self.progress} / {self.total}")
        self.progress += 1
        self.progress_changed.emit(self.progress)
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    backend = Backend()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend", backend)
 
    engine.load(os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "main.qml"))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    ret = app.exec_()
    # backend.worker_thread.quit()
    # backend.worker_thread.wait()
    sys.exit(ret)
```

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    id: mainWindow

    width: 750
    height: 500
    visible: true
    color: "#00000000"
    title: qsTr("Progress Bar")

    Row {
        spacing: 10
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Button {
            id: btnGenerate

            text: "start"
            onClicked: backend.start_worker()
        }

        ProgressBar {
            id: progressBar
            from: 0
            to: 100.0
        }

    }

    Connections {
        target: backend

        function onProgressChanged(progress) {
            progressBar.value = progress;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This works really well, thank you @eyllanesc. Where could I learn more regarding this as I'm struggling to learn the communication side of things between qml and py files.